# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am working on an MVC, which displays a list of requests to a user. The model looks something like this:

```
public class RequestModel 
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Requests.ToList());
}
```

I would like the index view page to show a list of the requests with status "Pending", which I have attempted with the following code:

```
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @if (modelItem => item.Status == "Pending")
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type "bool" because it is not a delegate type.

I am unsure what this errors means and how to work around it. If anyone has any help or advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just filter the collection before your pass it to the view - `return View(db.Requests..Where(x => x.Status == "Pending"));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your condition should look like:

```
@if (item.Status == "Pending")
```

You're trying to use lambda expression (`modelItem => item.Status == "Pending"`) where you should use simple condition.

Comment: make some boxing operation if it's a null able type

Comment: @Saneeshkunjunni what do you mean?

Comment: @DavidG ok, no problem, I only notice that some new users don't know how to do it

Comment: I find it's sometimes OK to explain how to use the site, but not to suggest anyone to vote or accept my own answers.

Comment: Great answer; but oh I wish the compiler would cover the lamba syntax case as well, one really has to 'dig' to find this

Answer (score 5):

By writing this `modelItem => item.Status == "Pending"` you are defining a function:

```
Func<string,bool> someFunc = (str) => str == "Pending";
```

and you get that your if statement looks something like the following, which means that instead of having a `bool` evaluated in the if statement you have a delegate object.

```
if(someFunc) // causes compilation error
{
    // some code
}
```

Notice that it is not calling the function and evaluating the boolean result which would be:

```
if(someFunc(item.Status))
{
    // some code
}
```

To correct it remove the `modelItem =>`

---

If in View you always want items that have the "Pending" status then consider moving the filtering logic to the controller but adding a `Where` clause on your returned collection.

Comment: I see, it was my first time using such a function, thank you for explaining it

Comment: @User2294 But surely not your first time using an `if` statement?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by other answers, `@if (item.Status == "Pending")` should fix your issue.

`modelItem => item.Status == "Pending"` creates a *`Func`*. (If you're new to anonymous methods and lamda expressions, these videos will be extremely helpful: [Tuts+](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmdziLz51w4), [kudvenkat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4trl43Ycksg) and [kudvenkat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDgQ-spnrYY))

Also, if you want only *Pending* items in your view, you can filter them in the Controller itself. If your requests table has thousands of records, then looping through them in your view is not efficient

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Requests.Where(r => r.Status == "Pending").ToList());
}
```